# Migrating MySQL 5.0 to 5.5 - simple databases

Tags: mysql-5, upgrade

I have a LAMP server on my LAN running a very old version of RedHat with MySQL 5.0, and I'm trying to migrate it to Ubuntu 12.04 to update it.

I know the advice is to migrate MySQL 5.0 to 5.1 then 5.2, and so on.  However, there are no triggers or stored procedures in these databases, just simple MyISAM and InnoDB tables and indexes.

Can anyone tell me what if I can just export the databases in 5.0 from the RedHat server using phpMyAdmin, and then import them into 5.5 on Ubuntu?

The data is mainly used by PHP to build dynamic web pages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make full back (preferably mysqldump)
2. Follow official guide : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html

and also this one http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-early-5-0.html

Comment: Thanks @rkosegi.  

1. I don't know how to start MySQL from the command line in RedHat. I'm using phpMyAdmin, which allows me to export all the tables as SQL, and I have been able to import them to the new server.

2. Yes, I knew about the official guide, that's where I read that I should migrate MySQL 5.0, to 5.1, then 5.2, and so on. But my question was whether I can avoid that.  I don't know how to get the intermediate versions of MySQL and install them in Ubuntu, or I would have just followed the official guide.

Re the second link, I just set up all the privileges from scratch.